# Android Canvas drawRect in loop

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

I want to draw a matrix of rectangles on my ui. The problem is that there is only one rectange, the first one of the matrix, visible.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
        a = w / 11;
        space = a / 12;
        System.out.println("w: " + w + ", h: " + h + ", a: " + a + "space: " + space);
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
                System.out.println("canvas.drawRect(new Rect(" + (x*a+(x+1)*space) + ", " + (y*a+(y+1)*space) + ", " + a + ", " + a + "), p);");
                canvas.drawRect(new Rect(x*a+(x+1)*space, y*a+(y+1)*space, a, a), p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This are the fist lines of the output:

```
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): w: 1080, h: 1701, a: 98space: 8
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 8, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 114, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 220, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 326, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 432, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 538, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 644, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 750, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 856, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 962, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 1068, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 1174, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 1280, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 1386, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 1492, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(114, 8, 98, 98), p);
05-08 15:04:19.511: I/System.out(26349): canvas.drawRect(new Rect(114, 114, 98, 98), p);
```

And here is a screenshot of the ui:
[image: screenshot]

So what am I doing wrong? There should be a 10x15 matrix of rectangles.

Comment: Is your `canvas` large enough to see all of the squares?

Comment: Also the order of parameters is `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`. Most of these squares have a `top` that's lower (on the screen) than their `bottom`, so I'm not sure what the behaviour would be. There's no range checking on `Rect`'s.

Comment: @Justin Jasmann - first Question: I think so. the View is set to match_parent and the screen has a resolution of 1080x1701. The View is the only Element in the xml file.

Comment: @JustinJasmann I thought the right and botom parameters were for the width and height of the rect, not for the position til which the rect should be drawn. Thanks. Please post it as answer.

Comment: Ahh, yeah the docs seem a little vague on it, but I think that's the solution. Posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the docs for [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and they say the params go `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`.

From your log output, it looks like your `top` is *below* the `bottom` (on the screen). It indicates in the documentation that range checks aren't done, so I'm guessing if one overlaps the other then it won't display the rectangle.

Hopefully that gets it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
        int left = x*a+(x+1)*space;
        int top  =  y*a+(y+1)*space;
        int right = a;
        int bottom = a;
        if( left <= right && top <= bottom ) {
            Log.d("draw","canvas.drawRect(new Rect("+left +", "+top+", "+right+", "+bottom+"), p);");
            canvas.drawRect(new Rect(left,top,right,bottom), p);
        }
    }
}
```

And only one rect was printed.

```
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(8, 8, 98, 98), p);
```

Maybe it is the rect in your screenshot.

You want a 10x15 matrix of rectangles.Do you mean this?

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
        a = w / 11;
        space = a / 12;
        System.out.println("w: " + w + ", h: " + h + ", a: " + a + "space: " + space);
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
                int px = x*a+(x+1)*space;
                int py = y*a+(y+1)*space;
                System.out.println("canvas.drawRect(new Rect("+px+", "+py+", "+(px+a)+", "+(py+a)+"), p);");
                canvas.drawRect(new Rect(px, py, px+a, py+a), p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be it. Thanks for your Answer, but it has already been answered.